# coefplot with rdrobust

Tags: stata, coefplot

In Stata I'm trying to plot  the coefficients of `rdrobust` estimates using `coefplot`:

```
foreach depvar of varlist var1 var2 var3 var4 {
    rdrobust `depvar' running_variable, kernel(triangular) bwselect(cerrd) p(1)
    estimates store  `depvar'
}

coefplot _est_var1 _est_var2 _est_var3 _est_var4 , replace xline(0)
```

But I get the following error message:

> estimation result _est_var1 not found

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1565051-coefplot-for-balance-tests-using-rdrobust  Telling people about cross-posting is always a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I have only changed the last line of your code and I wonder if it would work. As I do not have your data, I have not tested.

```
foreach depvar of varlist var1 var2 var3 var4{
  rdrobust `depvar' running_variable, kernel(triangular) bwselect(cerrd) p(1)
  estimates store  `depvar'
}
coefplot var1 var2 var3 var4, replace xline(0)
```

Comment: Thanks, but did not solve. The estimation is saving results as i named above.

Comment: It would be helpful for others to work out a solution if you could provide a reproducible sample.

Comment: @arabelo where exactly does the estimation save the results with the names you provide? `depvar` in your code expands to `var1`, `var2` and so on. Not `_est_var1`, `_est_var2` etc.

Comment: @arabelo There is a difference between estimation results stored by estimates store and the `_est_*` variable which only stores the sample used for your regression. Have a look at it, the variable only contains 0 and 1 to indicate which observations were used.